# Create a circuit that saves battery

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, timer, 555, battery-operated

I am trying to make a timer for myself. I select how long the timer runs for via a switch. The timer should begin counting down via a tilt sensor (or just a momentary button/switch to start) and count down until time expires. When time is up, an LED lights up for 5 seconds or until the start signal is triggered again. When the timer is not active, I would like the circuit to be completely interrupted so as to not drain the battery. I would like the whole thing to be run on a coin battery. I was thinking a small relay to interrupt the battery, but I'm not sure how to make that work at all.

I am new to designing circuits and need help speccing out the components. I am leaning toward using a microcontroller to run the logic on. Is the PIC10F200 a good choice for this? Are there other MC's I should look at instead? I suppose that I could design this with a 555 or similar chip but I think the flexibility of a MC would be nice if I don't want to change the circuit to make changes. Plus it needs to consume very little power to prevent eating up the battery.

Again, the requirements are:

- coin battery operated (CR2032)
- Tilt switch triggers the timer
- Timer length is 60 seconds to 20 minutes, selectable via switch.
- LED lights up when timer is done

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know the specific MCU, but it definitely will come with a datasheet that describes a stop mode and a low power mode current draw.

Comment: Other than that, this all sounds reasonable. I'm not quite sure what the question you're asking here is?

Comment: Thank you! I will check in on the datasheet for the stop mode and low power mode. I suppose I am just looking for an experienced designer to help prevent me from designing this circuit completely wrong.

Comment: Kyle: well, to be honest, that MCU is like, **really** minimal. So minimal in fact that I think you're making programming it harder than it needs to be! I think, realistically, you should be dividing your coin cell's capacity (in mAh, say 50 mAh) by the hours in your expected battery life (say, 2 years = 27520 h) and get the average current draw that's OK for your microcontroller (in this example, some 2.8 µA). And then you'd be looking for "larger" microcontrollers that are easier to program (and might more versatile sleep modes) but still reach that current goal. Think NXP's K32 L2.

Comment: I will look at the NXP. Keep in mind that I was looking at that MCU because it was very minimal and inexpensive. I guess the whole reason I was because all I am trying to do is count down and turn on an LED with a long battery life. If there is a better way, I am all for it!

Comment: @KyleRushing For maximum life with a battery, you'll probably want the MSP430. It's cheap and it uses nanoamps when sleeping and will start up in less than 2us to full speed. If someone knows of something better, I'd love to hear it. It will use less than the battery leakage, itself. However, the LED will be the party pooper here. It will chew through the battery energy some where between 15,000 and 100,000 times faster than the MCU. So 5 s of the LED will be about equal to a day and a half of just sitting there waiting.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive. I will definitely look at the MSP430. Are there any design resources I can access for writing the code for this MCU other than the datasheet? Also, I see at least 32 different versions of this processor. For lack of a better way, I would likely just pick the most inexpensive one and work my way up. I am pretty sure these will perform much more than I need for this relatively simple project.